# RxJs: Testing observable that depends on other observable/

Tags: angular, testing, rxjs, observable, angular-spectator

I have an observable called isSearchEnabled$, that indicates whether the search button on search form is clickable or not.
This is the code for the observable:

`isSearchEnabled$ = anotherObject.errorSource$.pipe(map((errors) => errors.length === 0);`

As one can see, this observable is depending on another observable, which emits an array every time form validation occurs. So isSearchEnabled emits a boolean true when the array is empty, false otherwise.

I wanna test this observable, but I'm not sure how. I should mock `anotherObject.errorSource$` to emit fake errors, and check whether `isSearchEnabled$` returns true or false?

How should i do it in Angular/RxJS?
If somebody have solution in spectator, or just a regular solution, I'd really appreciate it!

PS.: I know I should provide a working example, but I think this description is quiet straightforward, and no need further code.

Comment: This anotherObject is a service or simply an object that emits errors on the errorSource$ subject?

Comment: anotherObject is an Akita Query (state management query) that emits items from a store on change.
https://datorama.github.io/akita/docs/query/

Comment: But I think the only thing what important is what errorSource$ emits, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anotherObject is an object as you specify above you could do something like this. [AnotherObject Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ncjnsw?file=src/app/hello.component.spec.ts)

```
describe("HelloComponent", () => {
  let spectator: Spectator<HelloComponent>;

  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: HelloComponent,
    providers: [],
    detectChanges: false
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    spectator = createComponent();
  });

  it("should be disabled", done => {
    const errors = [new Error("xyz"), new Error("abc")];
    spectator.component.anotherObject = { errorSource$: of(errors) };
    spectator.detectChanges();
    spectator.component.isSearchEnabled$.subscribe({
      next: isSearchEnabled => {
        expect(isSearchEnabled).toBeFalse();
       //You might want to test here whether your component template/state changed..
        done();
      }
    });
  });

  it("should be enabled", done => {
    spectator.component.anotherObject = { errorSource$: of([]) };
    spectator.detectChanges();
    spectator.component.isSearchEnabled$.subscribe({
      next: isSearchEnabled => {
        expect(isSearchEnabled).toBeTrue();
        done();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

If you get the observable from the **akita query** the best option is to mock the query method your observable is dependent on. I haven't tested the code below, but something similar should work.

```
  let spectator: Spectator<HelloComponent>;
  let query: SpyObject<AkitaAnotherObjectQuery>;

  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: HelloComponent,
    mocks: [AkitaAnotherObjectQuery],
    detectChanges: false
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    spectator = createComponent();
    query = spectator.inject(AkitaAnotherObjectQuery);
    //return empty array to check if search is enabled by default
    query.selectErrorSource.andReturn(of([]));
  });

  it('should be enabled', () => {
     spectator.detectChanges();
     //todo test whether component state changed..
  });

  //test could be fake async or if you want to test the observable you can subscribe to it in the test below
  it('should be disabled', () => {
    const errors = [new Error('myError')];
    query.selectErrorSource.andReturn(of(errors));
    spectator.detectChanges();
    //todo test whether component state changed..
   });

  ....
```

Hope it works out, let me know if you have any more questions. If you want I can also add an example of the akita query mock in Stackblitz, just let me know.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot, but eventually I did in a different way, mocked ```errorSource$``` with a Subject, and emit errors with ```next()```, then i checked if isSearchEnabled$ emits true or false.

Comment: Is there a way to do it using marbles / TestScheduler?

Comment: Yes they enable you to test the async operations synchronously. In your question above I don't think you need it though. From what I understand you want to test whether the user can use the search input or not on component level. If you would to be performing multiple different queries based on your state change you'd want to test the operations in depth on query/service level not component level.